# Anyone know how to attach a touch listener to this class?

Tags: android, class, view, extend, ontouchlistener

```
package com.ewebapps;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class Dot extends View {
     private final float x;
     private final float y;
     private final int r;
     private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
     private final Paint mWhite = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

     public Dot(Context context, float x, float y, int r) {
         super(context);
         mPaint.setColor(0xFF000000); //Black
         mWhite.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF); //White
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
         this.r = r;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         super.onDraw(canvas);
         canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r+2, mWhite); //White stroke.
         canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint); //Black circle.
     }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to know just that the screen has been clicked or where it was clicked too?

Comment: I have many of these classes being clicked by a timer and i need to be able to tell which one of them was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... when creating your own views, the best way to accomplish that is overriding the `dispatchTouchEvent` method. Trust me, using `setOnTouchListener` and `onTouchEvent` don't work well in some scenarios. This is all you have to do in your `View`:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // put your logic here  

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: So using this method would I be able to test which instance of this class I clicked in the logic? (I have many of these classes being created and i need to be able to tell which one was clicked.) Thanks everyone for being so helpful! Everyone else everywhere could not answer my questions!

Comment: Of course, you can know which instance of the class was clicked, after all, all you do in the logic part will belong to that instance. I think you can use the Observer Design pattern to completely accomplish your goal, so go ahead and rock!

Comment: Thanks so much I tried all of these answers so far and yours is the one that worked. One thing though, is there anyway to make this a "private" boolean so that all the other instances of this object don't receive my this.invalidate(); call? (For when it redraws with a new sprite.)

Answer (score 0):

[documentation with example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)

```
View aView = (View)findViewById(R.id.DotView);
aView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

[Full Example Here](http://www.kellbot.com/2009/06/android-hello-circle/)

Comment: If I had more then one dot view would I be able to determine which was clicked by using your method? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Aaron Saunders answer works for views(like buttons) because an onTouchListener only tells you what view was clicked and not exactly where. If you need to know exactly where the event was without creating buttons try this in your activity class:

`@Override
    onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { 
        int _x = event.getX();

        int _y = event.getY();
        // do stuff
}`

Note: onTouchEvent is only called when the event is NOT handled by a view.
**[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)**

(*Can someone tell me how to add line breaks?*)

Comment: So I'm thinking about adding an argument to this class called dotnumber, if I had many instances of this dot and the dot number was different for each one, could I touch it and have it tell me what it's dot number was using this method? Thanks for the support, much appreciated my friend!

Comment: Yes, you could use the x and y coordinates of the event passed to onTouchEvent to see if where the screen was clicked was the same as one of your dots.